# Checking a box counting algorithm

Tags: geometry, fractals

I've been coding a box counting algorithm within a physic simulation to compute the fractal dimension of certain polygons. The results are .... not the ones expected, and there is more than probably something to debug in there. I've been testing the box counting algorithm on simple lines and cubes to derive their fractal dimension (1 and 2 of course) with success but I'd like to test it a bit further (before questioning the physical simulation itself) and test it on a real fractal. I've been looking on the internet for this without any luck, I would just need the point coordinates of a fractal 2d shape. Does someone have been manipulating something alike?

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found what I was looking for. 
Someone kindly shared it on the internet for the Koch snowflake:
https://github.com/tpllaha/Koch-Snowflake

Though I know now that my algorithm is not working.